# Usage of mmap and reloading changes to the file

Tags: unix, mmap

I'm using mmap to load a big file with just with READ-ONLY access.

It's expected, that a cron job overwrites this file, daily once with updated content.

My query here is that how would my executable re mmap the updated file to get to the updated content?
Do I need to call mmap again? How would my executable know at what time the file was updated?

What's the usual recommended ways and options available with tradeoffs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cron job just opens the file and overwrites the data in it, the new data should be immediately reflected in your mapped memory. If the cron job creates a new file, writes the data there, and then calls `rename()` to move the new file on top of the old, you need to close the old file and reopen to get the new data. This is often done to avoid data corruption in case of a power failure while rewriting the file.

As for how you get notified, there are several possibilities. The easiest might be to have the cron job just send a signal (e.g. `SIGUSR1`) to your process. You can then react to the signal and do your work. Otherwise, you could use [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (on Linux) to monitor your file for writes.

Another option is to periodically poll the file's [mtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29) to detect changes. Personally, I'd avoid that route though, as it seems rather hacky and inelegant.